# The text of button wont change

Tags: python, tkinter

Im making an tic tac toe but when the button got click the button wont change this the example

```
from tkinter import *
a = Tk()
def c():
    t = "X"

t = ""
b=Button(a, text= t, command=c)
b.pack()
a.mainloop()
```

This just an example plss give any way to change the text of button by calling

Answer (score 1):

The line `t = "X"` creates a new variable inside the function `c()`, which is then garbage collected when the function exits. Also the button text is not set.

You can change the button text with the `.config()` method:

```
from tkinter import *

a = Tk()

def c():
    b.config(text="X")

t = ""
b = Button(a, text=t, command=c)
b.pack()

a.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your t is not in the same scope.  For example:

```
def change():
   a=10000

a=100
print(a)
change()
print(a) 


OUTPUT:
100
100
```

Functions are like vegas, what happens there, stays there.  Read up on scope in more detail here:  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

It's been a while since I've used tkinter, but I do remember creating classes and using them was super helpful for keeping things string.

Here is an example of how to set up a class with a method to change it

```
from Tkinter import *


class Board:
    TurnMarker="X"
    root=Tk()

class button:
    def __init__(self,GameBoard,x,y):
           self.text=""
           self.x=x
           self.y=y
           self.GameBoard=GameBoard
           self.button=Button(GameBoard.root,self.text,command=self.set)
           self.button.grid(row=y,column=x)
    def set(self):
        self.button["text"]=self.GameBoard.TurnMarker
        if self.GameBoard.TurnMarker=="X":
            self.GameBoard.TurnMarker="O"
        else:
            self.GameBoard.TurnMarker="X"

board=Board()




for y in range(3):
    for x in range(3):
        b=button(board,x,y)
```

This is an example of using classes both for the buttons and board.  Classes make working with Tkinter much easier.